# Why is !0 equal to 1 and not -1?

Tags: c, logical-operators

The following code

```
printf("!%d = %d\n", 0, !0);
printf("!%d = %d\n", 1, !1);
printf("!%d = %d\n", -1, !-1);
```

gives

```
!0 = 1
!1 = 0
!-1 = 0
```

Now, considering that `0 = 0x00000000`, shouldn't `!0 = 0xFFFFFFFF = -1` (for signed representation)?
This messes up using `int` / `long` in a bitfield and inverting everything at once.

What is the reason behind this? Is it only to avoid `!1` to be considered as the boolean `true`?

Comment: `!` is not a binary not, it is a logical not.

Comment: Because "TRUE" is defined as 1 in C.  I've worked with a Pascal system where "TRUE" was defined as -1.  Ultimately, It just depends on how the standard is written.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The reason is that in standard C, it has been specified that all operators returning a boolean return either 1 or 0. !0 calculates the logical not of 0, i.e. 1. The logical not of 1 would be then 0.

What you want to use is the bitwise NOT operator, i.e. `~0` which should be `0xFFFFFFFF == -1`.

Comment: Thx, operator ~ is what I was looking for